# Expandable ListView

Tags: android

How  we can create Expandable ListView with group icon on Right.have any one implement it...

Comment: please make your question much clearer and edit it properly.

Comment: Do you mean 'expendable' or 'expandable'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<ExpandableListView android:id="@+id/Exlist"
    android:childDivider="#00000000" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:groupIndicator="transparent Image"
    android:scrollbars="none" android:listSelector="#00000000"
     android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dip" />
```

Above code "android:groupIndicator="transparent image"" becuase remove left side group indicator icon.

Now used below XML for Group Indicator file.

**group.xml**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/rlheaderName"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/main_down">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/headerName"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip" android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#6e6e6e" android:textStyle="bold"></TextView>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/headerCount"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip" android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#6e6e6e" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/headerName"></TextView>
</RelativeLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
```

Above file "android:background="@drawable/main_down"" main_down used as arrow in rightside.

so you problem solved.